# Recursive minimal tree creating function buggy?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

From an exercise in Cracking the Coding Interview: 
Given a sorted (increasing order) array with unique integer elements, write an algorithm that will create a binary search tree with minimal height.

The algorithm structure is:

1. Insert into the tree the middle element of array (is root).
2. Insert (into left subtree) the left subarray elements.
3. Insert (into right subtree) the right subarray elements.
4. Recurse.

But the actual code I believe is buggy. Given an array that holds {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, it'll insert the 6 twice into the left subtree. This is because of int mid = (start + end) / 2; The code will never insert node 7 into the left subtree tree because it is at index 1, and the mid variable won't evaluate to 1.

```
Node createMinimalBST(int arr[]) {
 return createMinimalBST(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

Node createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
 if (end < start) {
  return null;
 }

 int mid = (start + end) / 2;
 Node n = new Node(arr[mid]);
 n.left = createMinimalBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
 n.right = createMinimalBST(arr, mid + 1, end);
 return n;
}
```

Comment: 7 will be inserted to the right of 6

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the algorithm or the code logic.
Below is exactly how the binary search tree will look like after the insertions as per the code.

```
  8
 / \
6   9
 \   \
 7   10
```

Working code of the logic :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int value){
        val = value;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
}Node;

Node* createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (end < start)
        return NULL;

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    Node *n = new Node(arr[mid]);
    n->left = createMinimalBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
    n->right = createMinimalBST(arr, mid + 1, end);
    return n;
}

Node* createMinimalBST(int arr[], int size) {
    return createMinimalBST(arr, 0, size - 1);
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    Node *root = createMinimalBST(a, 5);

    cout << root->val << endl;
    cout << root->left->val << endl;
    cout << root->right->val << endl;
    cout << root->left->right->val << endl;
    cout << root->right->right->val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the code :

```
8
6
9
7
10
```

Comment: But as mid is decremented with each recursive call, for example when start = 0 and end = 4, mid becomes 2. You insert the root node which is 8. However then you recurse: start = 0 and end = mid - 1 = 1. mid becomes 0. You insert 6 as left child of 8. But when you recurse again, start = 0 and end = mid - 1 = 0. mid becomes 0. You REinsert 6 into the tree again... This is where I am confused. Is there not a bug?

Comment: Sorry! You are correct but I could not see it because I was making very simple dumb mistakes following the code... I was getting tunnel vision! Couldn't see what I was doing wrong. Thank you :)